# Error using the "App Lock" configuration profile setting (aka "kiosk mode") with an iPad/iOS6.0

Tags: ipad, mdm

Background:

Apple provides a "kiosk mode" for their iPads as part of iOS6 which locks the device into one application (even boots directly into the app too). Great for using iPads in retail/restaurants/etc.

In order to use this, the device first has to be setup as a "Supervised" device using Apple Configurator.  You then add a special entry to a configuration profile called "App Lock". I followed the [recently-updated configuration profile document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206). Essentially, you just set the PayloadType as 'com.apple.app.lock' and add a property called 'Identifier' which is set to the value of your application's bundle ID.

When I try to add the config profile to the iPad (whether through a Safari link, MDM, or Apple Configurator), it rejects it.

The console output in Xcode shows the following:

```
Sep 24 17:51:56 Test-iPad mc_mobile_tunnel[487] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Attempting to perform Supervised request: ProfileList
Sep 24 17:51:56 Test-iPad installd[30] <Error>: 0x2ff9f000 filter_attributes: Info.plist keys requested via MobileInstallationLookup/Browse in client Apple Configurator (via mobile_installation_proxy) were not found in MobileInstallation's cache. Please file a bug requesting that these keys be added: <CFBasicHash 0x1e58b0b0 [0x3d8f2100]>{type = mutable set, count = 1,
   entries =>
       2 : <CFString 0x3d8de564 [0x3d8f2100]>{contents = "CFBundleSignature"}
   }
Sep 24 17:51:57 Test-iPad mc_mobile_tunnel[492] <Notice>: (Error) MC: MCAppWhitelistPayload Can't parse payload: NSError:
   Desc   : The payload “Test Profile” is invalid.
   Sugg   : The field “App” is invalid.
   US Desc: The payload “Test Profile” is invalid.
   US Sugg: The field “App” is invalid.
   Domain : MCPayloadErrorDomain
   Code   : 2000
   Type   : MCFatalError
   Params : (
       "Test Profile"
   )
   ...Underlying error:
   NSError:
   Desc   : The field “App” is invalid.
   US Desc: The field “App” is invalid.
   Domain : MCPayloadErrorDomain
   Code   : 2003
   Type   : MCFatalError
   Params : (
       App
   )
Sep 24 17:51:57 Test-iPad mc_mobile_tunnel[492] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Payload “(null)” contains ignored fields. They are: <CFBasicHash 0x20819140 [0x3d8f2100]>{type = mutable dict, count = 1,
   entries =>
       1 : <CFString 0x1f527bd0 [0x3d8f2100]>{contents = "Identifier"} = <CFString 0x1f527c10 [0x3d8f2100]>{contents = "com.hubworks.myapp"}
   }
Sep 24 17:51:57 Test-iPad mc_mobile_tunnel[492] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Cannot create profile of type “com.apple.app.lock”. Error: NSError:
   Desc   : The payload “Test Profile” is invalid.
   Sugg   : The field “App” is invalid.
   US Desc: The payload “Test Profile” is invalid.
   US Sugg: The field “App” is invalid.
   Domain : MCPayloadErrorDomain
   Code   : 2000
   Type   : MCFatalError
   Params : (
       "Test Profile"
   )
   ...Underlying error:
   NSError:
   Desc   : The field “App” is invalid.
   US Desc: The field “App” is invalid.
   Domain : MCPayloadErrorDomain
   Code   : 2003
   Type   : MCFatalError
   Params : (
       App
   )
Sep 24 17:51:57 Test-iPad mc_mobile_tunnel[492] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Profile MCConfigurationProfile 0x1f526100, version 1:
   Display Name: “Test Profile”
   Identifier  : home-macbook-air.local.2A8DC5A2-937E-4246-B2AF-7C756C30C447
   UUID        : E06A5B33-9CD3-40CB-8611-0479E642B427
   Is Stub     : No
   Locked      : No
   Encrypted   : No
   Trusted     : 2
   Signed      : Yes
   Signed by   : Apple Configurator (58:55:CA:F7:24:B9)
    Can't parse profile: NSError:
   Desc   : The profile “Test Profile” is invalid.
   Sugg   : The payload “Test Profile” is invalid.
   US Desc: The profile “Test Profile” is invalid.
   US Sugg: The payload “Test Profile” is invalid.
   Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
   Code   : 1000
   Type   : MCFatalError
   Params : (
       "Test Profile"
   )
   ...Underlying error:
   NSError:
   Desc   : The payload “Test Profile” is invalid.
   Sugg   : The field “App” is invalid.
   US Desc: The payload “Test Profile” is invalid.
   US Sugg: The field “App” is invalid.
   Domain : MCPayloadErrorDomain
   Code   : 2000
   Type   : MCFatalError
   Params : (
       "Test Profile"
   )
   ...Underlying error:
   NSError:
   Desc   : The field “App” is invalid.
   US Desc: The field “App” is invalid.
   Domain : MCPayloadErrorDomain
   Code   : 2003
   Type   : MCFatalError
   Params : (
       App
   )
   Extra info:
   {
       isPrimary = 1;
   }
Sep 24 17:51:57 Test-iPad mc_mobile_tunnel[492] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Failed to parse profile data. Error: NSError:
   Desc   : The profile “Test Profile” is invalid.
   Sugg   : The payload “Test Profile” is invalid.
   US Desc: The profile “Test Profile” is invalid.
   US Sugg: The payload “Test Profile” is invalid.
   Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
   Code   : 1000
   Type   : MCFatalError
   Params : (
       "Test Profile"
   )
   ...Underlying error:
   NSError:
   Desc   : The payload “Test Profile” is invalid.
   Sugg   : The field “App” is invalid.
   US Desc: The payload “Test Profile” is invalid.
   US Sugg: The field “App” is invalid.
   Domain : MCPayloadErrorDomain
   Code   : 2000
   Type   : MCFatalError
   Params : (
       "Test Profile"
   )
   ...Underlying error:
   NSError:
   Desc   : The field “App” is invalid.
   US Desc: The field “App” is invalid.
   Domain : MCPayloadErrorDomain
   Code   : 2003
   Type   : MCFatalError
   Params : (
       App
   )
   Extra info:
   {
       isPrimary = 1;
   }
```

Comment: Here is the config profile I am using (with personally identifying information changed): http://www.pastebin.com/srB9iqHY

Answer (score 8):

**I figured it out!** I'm either misreading it or Apple left out a little detail in their [configuration profile reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html) . In order to avoid the error, the "Identifier"/bundleId key/value pair has to be wrapped in a dictionary, itself the value of a key named "App". See below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>App</key>
        <dict>
          <key>Identifier</key>
          <string>bundle_identifier_of_the_app</string>
        </dict>
        <key>PayloadType</key>
        <string>com.apple.app.lock</string>
        <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
        <string>#######-#######-#######-######</string>
        <key>PayloadUUID</key>
        <string>#######-#######-#######-######</string>
        <key>PayloadVersion</key>
        <integer>#</integer>
      </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>##########</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>######-#####-######-#####</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>######-######-#####-#####</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>#</integer>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Does this still apply for ios8? Also can it work on iPod Touch devices?

Answer (score 0):

Yes still working in iOS 9.1

and you can add options like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
<key>PayloadContent</key>
<array>
      <dict>
        <key>App</key>
        <dict>
          <key>Identifier</key>
          <string>bundle_identifier_of_the_app</string>
          <key>Options</key>
          <dict>
            <key>DisableAutoLock</key>
            <true/>
            <key>DisableVolumeButtons</key>
            <true/>
          </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>PayloadType</key>
        <string>###.#####.#####</string>
        <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.klangerfinder.lockdown</string>
        <key>PayloadUUID</key>
        <string>######-######-#####-#####</string>
        <key>PayloadVersion</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
      </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>AppLockDown</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>###.#####.#####</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>######-######-#####-#####</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
 </dict>
</plist>
```

There are lot of old post´s out there. This and the above are the actual working ones!!!