# Remotely ensuring a certain iOS app is continuously run

Tags: ios, mdm

I would like to use a series of iPads as remotely managed kiosks: continuously running a specific single app, restarting it if it crashes or the device reboots. The controls of the iPad will  not be reachable, so I do not need to block any of those. They will all have a 3G connection. I'll also need to be able to push app updates.

As far as I've seen, [Apple's mobile device management](http://www.apple.com/ipad/business/it-center/deployment-mdm.html) allows pushing updates of an app remotely. However, there appears to be no option to tell the OS to open a certain app.

I've taken a look at [fruitstrap](https://github.com/ghughes/fruitstrap) which allows one to install and open apps on a device attached to a Mac, in the same manner Xcode does. However, I can't attach a Mac to every iPad's dock connector. This is probably possible using a jailbreak, but I'd rather not rely on that, as it's uncertain whether that will always be available.

So, I'm looking for any ways to remotely open a specific installed app on an iOS device, using the device's 3G connection, or to configure the device itself to keep a specific app open all the time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration called AppLock which allows you to lock into some app in Kiosk style mode. As example, if you download [Apple Configurator](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/42201/apple-configurator) you will see possibility to configure it through UI.

Also, in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574895/error-using-the-app-lock-configuration-profile-setting-aka-kiosk-mode-with), you can look at how to create a profile with AppLock payload.

There are couple of things which are special regarding this configuration

- It could be installed only on "supervised" iOS device. To make device supervised, you have to prepare it with Apple Configurator which I mentioned.
- It locks iOS device in specified app (it disables home button)
- It switches to the locked app when you install AppLock profile.

Couple of notes on supervised devices:

- The standard way to handle such devices are prepare them with Apple Configurator and manage them through MDM
- Also, supervised mode limits to which computers you can connect your device.

And one more general note:

- I have no idea how Kiosk mode will play with managed app update.

Answer (score 0):

IOS6 does have a kiosk mode, see http://www.ipadenclosures.com/blog/posts/your-ipad-into-a-kiosk . Not sure if you can update the app remotely though.