# IOS 7 MDM Applock Issue

Tags: ios, mdm, configuration-profile

Hi i am facing a issue while installing IOS 7 MDM Applock payload. The profile is not showing install option on the device . I followed Apple Configuration reference document but no use. I checked with following url aslo but it is also not showing install option.

[Error using the "App Lock" configuration profile setting (aka "kiosk mode") with an iPad/iOS6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574895/error-using-the-app-lock-configuration-profile-setting-aka-kiosk-mode-with)

Any advice would be appriciated

Comment: I think what you're saying is that you can't successfully install a profile on a supervised device. Is that right ? If so, can you import your configuration file into the apple configurator successfully? Also I would try manually installing the profile on a device while its connected via xcode and look at the device console. There are helpful error messages that are shown on install and entering single app mode.

Comment: Device is not in super vised mode. That is the problem.